# Join table in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables that showing data `Item master` and `BOM`. I would like to join the tables between `Item master as T1` and `BOM as T2` and the additional table for table `BOM as T3`. Item master table containing `ITM_CD, ITM_TYP (1,2,3,4)` where each `ITM_TYP` represents a code for the first digit on `ITM_CD`. The thing that I want is like the picture below

[image]

**CHILD_CD2** value replace to **CHILD_CD1** value. So the data should be like this. What query should I fix ? I am very new using oracle query.

[image]

Here is mycode;

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.ITM_CD,
    T2.C_ITM_CD AS CHILD_CD1,
    T3.C_ITM_CD AS CHILD_CD2
FROM CM_HINMO_ALL T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT P_ITM_CD, C_ITM_CD, BOM_PTN FROM SM_BOM_ALL) T2 
ON T1.ITM_CD = T2.P_ITM_CD
        
LEFT  JOIN (SELECT P_ITM_CD, C_ITM_CD, BOM_PTN FROM SM_BOM_ALL) T3 
ON T2.C_ITM_CD = t3.P_ITM_CD
WHERE 0=0
AND T2.BOM_PTN IN (1)
AND T1.ITM_TYP IN (1,2)
AND T1.ITM_CD = '110100370'
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: Apart from the issue you have mentioned, is everything fine with the query ? I mean the join between `T2` and `T3` in particular I am interested in ?

Comment: Join table between T2 and T3 does not a problem I guess.
I just want to breakdown the BOM of Parent Item CD, what material and component that has been used as Child Item CD without inserting Item WIP(Work In Process)

ITM TYP 
 1 : Product
 2 : Work In Process
 3 : Material
 4 : Component

Answer (score 1):

Just use Case expression to replace the values.

```
SELECT ITM_CD, CASE WHEN CHILD_CD2 IS NULL THEN CHILD_CD2 ELSE CHILD_CD1 END AS CHILD_CD1
    FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: It does not give any error message, but the value of CHILD_CD1 that showed up only Begins with the first digit 2...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, you want `child_cd2` value should taken precedence over `child_cd1` if available. If this assumption is right then we can use `coalesce` which returns the fist non null expression to achieve the same.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.ITM_CD,
    COALESCE(T3.C_ITM_CD,T2.C_ITM_CD) AS CHILD_CD1
  FROM CM_HINMO_ALL T1
  INNER JOIN SM_BOM_ALL T2 
     ON T1.ITM_CD = T2.P_ITM_CD
  LEFT JOIN SM_BOM_ALL T3 
     ON T2.C_ITM_CD = t3.P_ITM_CD
  WHERE T2.BOM_PTN IN (1)
    AND T1.ITM_TYP IN (1,2)
    AND T1.ITM_CD = '110100370'
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: Your assumption is right, it works for me. Thank you very much

Comment: @Nurman Ade, Nice. would be nice If any answers solve your issue , you can accept it by giving a tick and you don't have to  if the answer doesn't satisfy your requirements and additionally if any other answers give you some idea, you also can give a up-vote to it. This is the way you show your appreciation to those who tried to help you.